# How to identify a datapoint in a QQplot

Tags: r, graph, normal-distribution

I´m analyzing a residual´s QQplot to assess if they can be assumed to be normally distributed, and I have some datapoints that appear far away from the theoretical straight line. My question is: is there any way I can ask R to identify those specific points, so I can study and try to understand them better?
**THANKS!**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is something **magical** you can do with plots. First generate a QQ plot:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> x <- rexp(100,100)
> qqpoints <- qqnorm(x)
```

Now use `identify` which will help you call out the points on the edges. Type this line and press the enter key:

```
> identify(qqpoints)
```

Go to the plot, and click on one of the outliers. Then hit ESCAPE. Do it a few times for each point you want to call out.

```
> identify(qqpoints)
[1] 37
> identify(qqpoints)
[1] 60
> identify(qqpoints)
[1] 27
> identify(qqpoints)
[1] 75
```

Each of the numbers that pops out is the index of the point you want to know more about. You can get individual coordinates of them like this:

```
> qqpoints$x[37]
[1] 2.575829
> qqpoints$y[37]
[1] 0.04324563
```

And the actual value of the point in the distribution like this:

```
> x[37]
[1] 0.04324563
```

And the labels will appear on the plot:

[image: qqpoints]

If you don't know which ones are outliers and you need to figure that out first, use `qqPlot` from the `car` package **then** `identify` the points that fall outside the confidence limits graphically:

```
> library(car)
> qqPlot(x)
```

[image: qqPlot]

Comment: Dear mysteRious, your answer has VERY helpful, it was exactly what I needed. Can't thank enough!

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the feedback, really appreciate it :)

Comment: MysteRious, I'm sorry for bothering again but I just realized this  procedure is for a dataset you geneerate with the `set.seed` function; how do I apply this to my data set?  I don't get the syntaxis in a 100%, so what should I replace in the code you wrote to get it done on my dataset? THANKS!

Comment: I just did this example on a sample of 100 data points from an exponential distribution with a mean of 1/100 -- which I stored in the variable x. The `set.seed` just makes it so you can type everything like in the example and you will get the same answers. To do this on your problem, just load your quantitative data into `x` and the rest of the code will work as-is.

Comment: Tried it and was able to identify the data points in the actual QQplot generated from my data , thanks a lot again!

Comment: Sorry to resurrect but will this work with the qqman package also?